# I can't get the images from us.gcr.io in Spinnaker pipeline trigger configuration

Tags: google-cloud-platform, spinnaker

I followed this tutorial from Google (https://cloud.google.com/solutions/continuous-delivery-spinnaker-container-engine), It's worked fine, but, in step of pipeline creation (automated triggers with Docker Registry), I can't get the images from `us.gcr.io`. Anyone with the same problem? Any log (of microservices) can help me?

Answer (score 1):

Its possible that the docker address specified in your spinnaker configuration is `gcr.io`. It should be `us.gcr.io`

Comment: Sorry for the late, my credentials configuration was wrong.